# Gitlab CI execute SAST jobs only when merging branch to master

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

Hello I'm trying to figure out how to run SAST jobs only when merging branch into master because they last 5 minutes and they are being run in every push for any branch.

This means that every time someone makes a push to their MR branch the security stage is executed with all SAST jobs.

What I want to achieve is that SAST jobs are executed when the branch is going to be merged to master.

**gitlab-ci.yml:**

```
include:
  - template: Jobs/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml

stages:
  - security
  - tests

my_tests:
  stage: tests
  script:
    - echo Running tests ...

sast:
  stage: security
```

What I tried so far is using:

```
sast:
  stage: security
  only: 
    - master
```

But it fails because the included template `Jobs/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml` already uses rules and rules with only/except can't be used together.

> jobs:sast config key may not be used with `rules`: only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [sourcecode](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml) `Jobs/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml` does not use `except` but `rules` which also are incompatible with `only`.

But you could also switch to rules syntax:

```
sast:
  stage: security
  rules:
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH"
      when: always
```

That should do the trick

Comment: Tested and does not work, sast explicitly has when never set and is only used for template inclusion, Mohammad Kamrani's answer functions as expected though if they add more runners they wouldn't be included :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use this configuration:

```
include:
  - template: Jobs/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml

phpcs-security-audit-sast:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event' 
      exists:
        - '**/*.php'

semgrep-sast:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
      exists:
         - '**/*.go'
         - '**/*.html'
         - '**/*.js'
         - '**/*.jsx'
         - '**/*.ts'
         - '**/*.tsx'

gosec-sast:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
      exists:
        - '**/*.go'

nodejs-scan-sast:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
      exists:
        - '**/package.json'

bandit-sast:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
      exists:
        - '**/*.py'

flawfinder-sast:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
      exists:
        - '**/*.c'
        - '**/*.cpp'

eslint-sast:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
      exists:
        - '**/*.html'
        - '**/*.js'
        - '**/*.jsx'
        - '**/*.ts'
        - '**/*.tsx'

spotbugs-sast:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
      exists:
        - '**/*.groovy'
        - '**/*.java'
        - '**/*.scala'
        - '**/*.kt'
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing by answering questions! When you post an answer that has a lot of code (like this one), it's always good practice to explain in words what the answer is/which parts are most interesting in the code. This helps in maintaining good quality over here on Stackoverflow!